# How long do sunflower seeds stay viable?

Tags: seeds, sunflowers

How long do sunflower seeds stay viable?

I'm thinking about getting several kinds, but I might not want to grow every variety every year. These are mostly large-seeded varieties meant for eating.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to this temperate climate permaculture site, [they stay viable](http://tcpermaculture.com/site/2013/06/14/how-long-will-seeds-last-stay-viable/) for 5 to 7 years. It lists the viability of a number of kinds of seeds, and I recognize the lengths stated for some seeds as being those I've seen listed elsewhere.

However, [this site](http://homeguides.sfgate.com/collect-sunflower-seeds-replanting-41735.html) says to consider sunflower seeds viable for the coming season only. It doesn't sound as if they know exactly how long they last, though; so, maybe this is just a precaution.

One of the comments on [this site](http://sunflower.tips/planting/) says they stay viable for 'a good few years if kept in the right conditions'. So, I think that backs up the 5 to 7 year claim.

Answer (score 2):

In general commercial seeds are viable for at least a year if kept dry, dark and cool (below 70 F). Dry is very important and you may want to use a metal container and toss in a desiccant package.